# EpiServer - IContentLoader returns different page types when filtering for the start page

Tags: c#, episerver, optimizely

I'm trying to get the start pages in Razor code so I can display different navs based on the start page. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
var contentLoader = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
var pages = contentLoader.GetChildren<PageData>(ContentReference.StartPage);
```

This is what shows up in the debugger. I was expecting to only see pages of type, Start. But I'm seeing Hero pages and everything. Any ideas what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by passing in the ContentReference for the root page and my start page object.

```
var pages = contentLoader.GetChildren<namespace.StartPage>(ContentReference.RootPage);
```

Comment: Do you have several start pages? In your question you say "I'm trying to get the start page in Razor code so I can display different navs based on the start page", and for the part "the start page", that indicates that there only is one instance of the start page which makes this not the right way to do it.

Comment: @MarcusÅberg it was just a typo. there are multiple start pages

Comment: Hey @ernest I want to offer some advice, forgive me if the above is just yourself debugging.

Using ServiceLocator to get an instance of ContentLoader in a Razor page is not a recommended best-practice. Instead you should consider Injecting the service into your PageController and passing what you need to your View via a ViewModel. 

I don't understand the reason to get all StartPages. I'm concerned you will end up with a big hardcoded condition to determine what to display. 

For Nav it's common for a StartPage or SiteSettingsPage to have ContentArea property to hold Nav Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the start page (just one instance) and it is the same start page that is selected as start page in admin mode for the configuration of your site you should do the following

```
var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);
```

Comment: There are multiple start pages. And I had to use the RootPage content reference. The start page content reference didn't work in my testing. Which is why I chose my answer.